# Convert torch models with reshape layers to onnx with dynamic shape

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I used export.py in [yolov5-face](https://github.com/deepcam-cn/yolov5-face) repository, and set dynamic_axes as follows:

```
      dynamic_axes = {'input': {
                        2: "?",
                        3: "?"},
                        'output': {
                        1: "?",
                        }
                        }
```

to convert the model to onnx with a dynamic shape.

The model converted successfully. I visualize the model with Netron and seems that is correctly converted with a dynamic shape:

[image]

But, when I get the inference with a 1280x1280 input shape, I get this error:

[image]

This seems that some models with reshape layers can not be converted to onnx with dynamic shape. But there must be a solution for these models!!

I still couldn't find it!

Has anyone encountered this problem and can help?